# Does anybody know how to display additional Intellisense in Phalanger?

Tags: php, comments, phalanger

I just installed Phalanger on VS 2008. Intellisense is working fine but I miss additional info about my own functions in Intellisense. Is there something like

```
/**
/* param value
*/
```

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I think, this was experimentally implemented and then disabled. You can only request for this feature the Phalanger team on codeplex.

Jakub